# how can I get this pattern in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

how can I get this pattern in product detail page in prestashop 1.6 ?
where I can add quantity according to size and color of product and then click add to cart.
[image: product detail page]

Comment: You'd have to modify both `product.tpl` and `cart-summary.js` for this. But beware, the JS part is really tricky and extensive. Displaying that layout should be rather easy in the .tpl though.

Comment: thanks for reply. but is there any ready made module to get this feature ?